# Expected vertex in a tetrahedron

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The following is taken from [this problem sheet for quant interviews](http://www.math.kent.edu/%7Eoana/math60070/InterviewProblems.pdf)

> A bug crawls along the edges of a regular tetrahedron ABCD with edges
> length 1. It starts at A and at each vertex chooses its next edge at random
> (so it has a $1/3$ chance of going back along the edge it came on, and a $1/3$ chance of going along each of the other two). Find the probability that
> after it has crawled a distance 7 it is again at A.

Numerical simulations suggest that the answer is $1/4$, but I'm not sure if that's right. On the first step the distribution is $(0,1/3,1/3,1/3)$, and on the second step it is $(1/3,2/9,2/9,2/9)$. I can continue doing this but my interviewer would be bored out of his/her mind! Is there a slick way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a simple example of a [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain). The wanted probability is $M_{11}$ where
$$ M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{3}\\ \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{3}\\ \frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{3}& 0& \frac{1}{3}\\ \frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{3} & 0\end{pmatrix}^7 $$
hence the answer is $\color{red}{\frac{182}{729}}$, very close to one fourth. If you group together the vertices $B,C,D$ in a single state (this is known as *lumping*, sometimes) you may check that the wanted probability can be computed as $N_{11}$, too, where:
$$ N = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ \frac{1}{3} & \frac{2}{3}\end{pmatrix}^7.$$
Even trickier: since the eigenvalues of the last $2\times 2$ matrix are $1$ (no wonder, it is a stochastic matrix) and $-\frac{1}{3}$, the probability of going from $A$ to $A$ in $n$ steps is
$$ p_n = k_1 + k_2\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^n $$
where $p_0=1$ and $\lim_{n\to +\infty}p_n=\frac{1}{4}$, hence the answer is given by
$$ \frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)^7 = \color{red}{\frac{1}{4}\left(1-\frac{1}{3^6}\right)}.$$

Comment: Aha! I feel so silly for missing this.

Comment: +1 You kept adding the next thing I was going to post just before I posted it. So I will just go with the first and a comment on the near uniformity of the distribution after $7$ steps.

Comment: @robjohn: sorry for the "chamaleon answer", I just realized too late there was a simple way for computing $p_n$. (+1) back, so your efforts are not wasted.

Answer (score 1):

As Jack D'Aurizio states
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&\frac13&\frac13&\frac13\\
\frac13&0&\frac13&\frac13\\
\frac13&\frac13&0&\frac13\\
\frac13&\frac13&\frac13&0
\end{bmatrix}^{\,\large7}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{#C00000}{\frac{182}{729}}&\frac{547}{2187}&\frac{547}{2187}&\frac{547}{2187}\\
\frac{547}{2187}&\frac{182}{729}&\frac{547}{2187}&\frac{547}{2187}\\
\frac{547}{2187}&\frac{547}{2187}&\frac{182}{729}&\frac{547}{2187}\\
\frac{547}{2187}&\frac{547}{2187}&\frac{547}{2187}&\frac{182}{729}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
the probability of getting back to the original vertex is $\frac{182}{729}\doteq0.249657$.

It is interesting to note that the distribution after $7$ steps is $\frac1{2187}\left\{\vphantom{\frac11}546,547,547,547\right\}$; almost uniform.

---

**Computing the General Transfer Matrix**

Let
$$
C=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
and $I$ be the $4$-dimensional identity matrix. Note that $C^n=4^{n-1}C$ for $n\ge1$.

The transfer matrix is
$$
M=\frac13(C-I)
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
M^n
&=\frac1{3^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}C^k\\
&=\frac1{3^n}(-1)^nI+\frac1{3^n}\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}C^k\\
&=\frac1{3^n}(-1)^nI+\frac{C}{4\cdot3^n}\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}4^k\\
&=\frac1{3^n}(-1)^nI-\frac{C}{4\cdot3^n}(-1)^n+\frac{C}{4\cdot3^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}4^k\\
&=\frac C4+\left(-\frac13\right)^n\left(I-\frac C4\right)
\end{align}
$$
The top-left element of $M^n$ is $\frac14+\frac34\left(-\frac13\right)^n$.

Note that $M^n$ converges to $\frac C4$ geometrically.